# Jquery validation on numbers with plus minus optional

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am working on MVC4 project where i have textbox in which i have to enter max 5 numbers but those number could be -ive or +ive

So i am using custom jquery validation but this is not satisfying the requirement
here is validation expression i am using

```
 "onlyNumberSp": {
                    "regex": /^[0-9]+$/,
                    "alertText": "* Numbers only"
                },
```

I know this is not correct expression so how can i achieve this functionality where user can enter max of 5 numbers with - or + or may not enter any sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"onlyNumberSp": {
    "regex": /^-?\d{1,5}$/,
    "alertText": "* Numbers only"
},
```